# Modify the javascript function called on button click

Tags: javascript, html

At our office we check in by opening a webpage and clicking on a check-in button.The following function is called while clicking the button:

```
function checkInOutSubmit(thisController, thisAction, checkName){
            var visitortime = new Date();
            var visitortimezone = "GMT " + -visitortime.getTimezoneOffset() / 60;
            var timeZone = jstz.determine_timezone();
            var timeZoneName = timeZone.name();
            var checkInCheckOut = checkName
            jQuery.ajax({type:'POST',data:{checkInCheckOut:checkInCheckOut,currentController: thisController,currentAction: thisAction,timez:timeZoneName}, url:'/pms/attendanceForgot/checkInCheckOut',success:function(data,textStatus){jQuery('#successdiv').html(data);successCheckInOut();},error:function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus,errorThrown){}});

        }
```

But I want to put a old time when clicking on the button and not the current time.(If I reach click the button at 11:00am, I want to post 10:00am as my checkin time).

How can this be done?

Comment: You can do it modify `visitortimezone` and adjust it to your intent, but I'm sure that `timeZone` and `timeZoneName` are variables dedicated to avoid smart ass. Be careful jejeje

Comment: I modified the time zone of my computer and checked in. The attendance report showed my required result. But how can this function of value of visitortimezone be varied from the browser itself,so this hack is FUD.

Answer (score 1):

There is not enough information here to answer your question.

All this code is doing is finding the current *time zone*, not the current *time*.  It passes that to the server via an ajax request, which makes me think the time is generated server side.  It's possible you could alter the logged time on the server by changing the timezone to an offset that would make it look like you are clocking in at the right time, but it would have to be some seriously deficient code on the server for that to work.

In almost all likelihood, the server is storing the time of the request in universal time as the clock in time and when you leave it's storing the time you leave in universal time as well.  (think a point in time that isn't dependent on timezones)  If your goal is get more hours, you'll just have to work later when you come in late.  If you want it to look like you came in "on time", then changing the timezone might help until they notice that you've been there from 10am to 6pm but are only logging 7 hours.